# Spring @Autowired annotation. How to create object that have relation to object in db?

Tags: spring, constructor, dependency-injection, autowired

I have entity model that have relation to other object stored in db.
When I first object, I have in constructor add id of the other object.
But when I constructor body I have to get from db whole object (second one) and sign it as relation. Using dao in model gives me `nullPointerException`. 
How can I achive this?

Here is constructor:

```
@Transient @Autowired public SkeletonElementDao skeletonElementDao;


public SkeletonElement(Long id, String name, Long parent_id) {
    super(id, name);
    SkeletonElement parentSkeletonElement = null;
    try {
        parentSkeletonElement = skeletonElementDao.get(parent_id);
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Creating element without parent_old   ");
    } finally {
        this.setParent(parentSkeletonElement);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: How can Spring autowire fields before a constructor is called?

Comment: I do not know that. But I have something like that to be done :D

Comment: Use constructor injection.

Comment: Your entities shouldn't depend on DAOs. JPA creates your entities, not Spring. The caller of the constructor should be the one using the DAO to get the parent, and pass the parent, rather than its ID, to the constructor.

Comment: I thought that've been doing that. Can You give me some code examples. I'have to somehow get to dao in constructor.

Comment: **jb-nizet** So instead of giving in constructor parameter Long parent_id I should give whole parent object class?

Comment: Yes: `Skeleton parent = dao.findOne(parentId); Skeleton child = new Skeleton(parent, ...);`

Comment: And this is my problem, cause constructor is called inside custom TypeAdapter (of GSON library) Where @autowiring dosnt work- gives me nullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Try the @PostConstruct annotation. Spring can only auto-wire fields AFTER the constructor is called.

```
@Transient @Autowired public SkeletonElementDao skeletonElementDao;

public SkeletonElement(Long id, String name, Long parent_id) {
    super(id, name);
    //Store these to private final fields
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    SkeletonElement parentSkeletonElement = null;
    try {
        parentSkeletonElement = skeletonElementDao.get(parent_id);
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Creating element without parent_old   ");
    } finally {
        this.setParent(parentSkeletonElement);
    }
}
```

Other way is to use [constructor injection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/constructor_based_dependency_injection.htm)

Comment: It wont work, cause in inint() method I dont have access to skeletonElementDao object. It have to be done outside the model class

Comment: "You don't have access", as in "I can't use it there", or as "It is not there"
BC skeletonElementDao should be injected before the init() method runs.

Comment: I think that to constructor I should inject an ready object of parent as it was pointed to me by  **JB Nizet** in one of answers. I think that `skeletonElementDao` exist only in `@Controller` annotated classes. Not in model class!